# Error when including the zoo package in R

Tags: r, installation, package, zoo, version-compatibility

When I tried to include the zoo package, I received the following error information:

```
> library(zoo)
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 
     '/Users/zhangfan/Library/R/2.13/library/zoo/libs/i386/zoo.so':
  dlopen(/Users/zhangfan/Library/R/2.13/library/zoo/libs/i386/zoo.so, 6):
    Library not loaded: @rpath/R.framework/Versions/2.13/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/zhangfan/Library/R/2.13/library/zoo/libs/i386/zoo.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'zoo'
```

Could anyone explain what that means?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same error after trying to install zoo recently. I fixed it by installing from source.

```
install.packages("zoo", type="source", repos="http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/")
```

Answer (score 5):

That looks a whole lot like the errors that Mac /User/'s were getting last week with the new GUI R.app that went along with R 2.14.0. Simon Urbanek fixed it several days ago, if those details fit your situation the first thing to try would be to install the new GUI from either CRAN or  http://r.research.att.com/

If ion the other hand you are trying to install the new zoo-package from CRAN while running R 2.13.x you might want to upgrade R (at the same locations)  to prevent major version mismatch.

Comment: Thanks DWin! R 2.13.x causes no end of problems with zoo (and other packages). Upgrade your R. As of 3/30/2012, current is 2.15.0 btw.